# React Native - Send Cookies to WebView

Tags: javascript, react-native

So there's a very simple example in the [documentation](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Guide.md#Managing-Cookies) that shows how you can pass cookies to a Webview:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <WebView
      source={{
        uri: 'http://example.com',
        headers: {
          Cookie: 'cookie1=asdf; cookie2=fdsa; cookie3=aaaa',
        },
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

How can I pass some attributes to each cookie?

If I open the Console in Google Chrome I can paste the following:

```
document.cookie ='cookie1=asdf;domain=.mydomain.com;path=/;'
document.cookie ='cookie2=fdsa;domain=.mydomain.com;path=/;'
document.cookie ='cookie3=aaaa;domain=.mydomain.com;path=/;'
```

This sets 3 cookies in the browser. Which is cool. If I try in React Native

```
const App = () => {
      return (
        <WebView
          source={{
            uri: 'http://example.com',
            headers: {
              Cookie: 'cookie1=asdf;domain=.mydomain.com;path=/;cookie2=fdsa;domain=.mydomain.com;path=/;cookie3=aaaa;domain=.mydomain.com;path=/;',
            },
          }}
        />
      );
    };
```

this will *probably* set 5 different cookies in the WebView: `cookie1, cookie2, cookie3, domain, path`

Comment: @YannickEich not trying to retrieve a cookie, I have some cookies in the mobile application generated from somewhere else that need to be sent in the WebView

Comment: Found a solution yet?